# JavaScript - Looping and adding a key value pair to JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm attempting to sort through 'response', a JSON object passed through the function from an API, and insert a key 'img:' and a value, the image src, based on the planet's name.

**What I have tried:**
I tried using response.push as found in a few StackOverflow links, but that just adds the key value to the entire object as a separate value. I also tried response[i], but that doesn't seem to be valid since my console gives me an error.

**A Few of the Links I've Visited** These are helpful, but don't seem to address the looping sequence I'm after.

- [Appending a key value pair to a json object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14272051/appending-a-key-value-pair-to-a-json-object)
- [How can I add a key/value pair to a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168807/how-can-i-add-a-key-value-pair-to-a-javascript-object-literal)
- [JS JSON Pair Key & Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296697/js-json-pair-key-value)

I would appreciate any help or guidance.

```
  app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, parseService) {

  $scope.getParseData = function() {
    parseService.getPlanet().then(function(response) {

      for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++)
        if (response[i].name === "Hoth") {
          console.log("We found hoth!");
          response.push({'img': 'testpic.jpg'}); //Trouble w. this line
        } else {
          console.log("not Hoth");
        }
        $scope.planets = response;

    });
  }
  $scope.getParseData();

});
```

Comment: Can you change `console.log('We found hoth!')` to `console.log(response)` and post the results? It'd be helpful to know what that object is. My guess is that it isn't an array, so you need to do something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will add the img: property:

```
response['img'] = 'testpic.jpg';
```

Comment: This is actually similar to the answer in the second article you linked to in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the nudge in the right direction. I had to do

`response[i]['img'] = 'testpic.jpg'; `

and this worked perfectly. I don't know why I didn't see that as an option. I'm still pretty new to this stuff. Thank you for your help!